# How to render react using python routes?

Tags: python, reactjs

I want to use this route here (below) and render my react file. Using a python route.... Could someone give me some direction on how I can accomplish this?

```
@Auth.route('/login', methods=['GET'])
def login():
    #data = {'username':'bob', 'password':'peepee123'}
    #session['token'] = 'jsdkfkj934ujeklfjdlndsflds'

auth = request.authorization

if auth and auth.password == 'password':
    token = jwt.encode({'user': auth.username}, app.config['SECRET_KEY'])

    return jsonfiy({'token': token.decode('UTF-8')})

return make_response('Could Not verify!', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm = "Login Required"'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render react in server site in python you can use [python-react-v8](https://github.com/nitely/python-react-v8), but you need to have the same react tree in server and client or it wont work, checkout [hydrate in docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate). For that you need to have working react app.

Example of usage:

```py
import react

# setup react
react.set_up() # Initialize V8 machinery
react.utils.load_libs(['./bundle.js'])

@Auth.route('/login', methods=['GET'])
def login():
    #data = {'username':'bob', 'password':'peepee123'}
    #session['token'] = 'jsdkfkj934ujeklfjdlndsflds'

auth = request.authorization

if auth and auth.password == 'password':
    token = jwt.encode({'user': auth.username}, app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    data =  {'token': token.decode('UTF-8')};
    react_ = react.React({
        'url': request.get_full_url(),
        'data': data
    })

    context = {
        'content': react_.render(),
        'data': react_.to_json(data)}

    return render('index.html', context);

data = {'token': null, 'reason': "Login Required"}
react_ = react.React({
    'url': request.get_full_url(),
    'data': data
})

context = {
    'content': react_.render(),
    'data': react_.to_json(data)
}

return render('index.html', context);
```

Comment: when i import react I get this error when i try to run flask AttributeError: module 'react' has no attribute 'set_up'

Comment: What can I do to import react properly to python?

Comment: And just to be very clear, what you wrote above is code for python right?

Comment: I just edited your example, just write it to explain what I mean. Did you install react through `pip install python-react-v8`?

Comment: There are examples in [python-react-v8](https://github.com/nitely/python-react-v8/tree/master/examples) repository, might be helpful.